# Strip All Urls From A Mixed String ( php )

Tags: php

i reposted this question because i didn't find a good answer.

i have a string which can contains text with urls.

i want a function to strip all urls from this string and just let the text.

by example the string can contains like this :

1) hey take a look here : http://xxx.xxx/545df5 this is nice!

2) hey take a look here : http://www.xxx.xxx/545df5 this is nice!

3) hey take a look here : xxx.xxx/545df5 this is nice!

4) hey take a look here : www.xxx.xxx/545df5 this is nice!

Thanks

Comment: Why repost when you can start a bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Regular expression for URL](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm) and [how to use regular expression with php](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a solid regex to find urls in a string and you can preg_replace that pattern with nothing. I can tell you though that tracking down a regex like that is not easy. Depending on the variations in the urls you're looking for (i.e. http:// vs https:// vs ftp://) You could run into real trouble trying to account for all that.

[Here is a page that I found to be a good start though](http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/).

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the way to go as was discussed prior.  Finding one isn't that terribly hard (google: url regex pattern) One example returned is here

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm

I would also recommend you test your regex using one of the many fine online regex testers.  My favorite (for non-java) is

http://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it(assuming your strings are seperated by space " "):

```
function isValidURL($url) {
    return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}

function cleanUpUrls($urls) {
    $urlArray = explode(' ',$urls);
    $resultArray = array();
    foreach ($urlArray as $url) {
        if(!isValidURL($url)) {
            $resultArray[] = $url;
        }
    }
    return implode(' ',$resultArray);
}
```