# Remove Url from String by finding by .com

Tags: php, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip All Urls From A Mixed String ( php )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051977/strip-all-urls-from-a-mixed-string-php)

i need a way to remove url strings from var but not with finding the `.` then remove it. no, i need it by finding `http` and finding `.com` or `.net` or `.info` then remove the whole link

here is my previoys code

```
    function cleaner($url) {
  $U = explode(' ',$url);

  $W =array();
  foreach ($U as $k => $u) {
    if (stristr($u,'http') || (count(explode('.',$u)) > 1)) {
      unset($U[$k]);
      return cleaner( implode(' ',$U));
    }
  }
  return implode(' ',$U);
}

$url = "$first";
```

but that one remove the . not .com

Comment: not what i want bro. i need to remove .com .info etc and i dont to work on it with dots only

Comment: Perhaps you could update the question then, so that what you want is clear. I.e. "I have this string, I expect this output, I tried this, I got this". Or simply [read this and "related"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match method to catch the stuff between http and .com

```
preg_match('%^((https?://)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i', $url);
```

I think the simplest way to accomplish this but not error free is:

```
$url="http://codepad.org/";
$arry=explode(".",$url);
$arry1= explode("//",$arry[0]);
echo $arry1[1];
```

Comment: but that will make it remove urls when it finds a (dot) and dats not what i want

Comment: then your answer is a dupliate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051977/strip-all-urls-from-a-mixed-string-php

Comment: bro at that answer i cant see anything that says .com or .net or something that